# Working with Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string,int> in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I need to get string values from the above nested dictionary. How to do it.
I have keypairvalue from datatable [3 columns] to Dictionary like this

```
management = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(m => m.Field<int>("ID"))
               .ToDictionary(
                   a => a.Key,
                   a => a.GroupBy(c => c.Field<string>("Name"))
                         .ToDictionary(
                             d => d.Key,
                             d => d.First().Field<int>("Parent")));
```

string temp = management???

Edit: Let me elaborate a bit.

I have a Management table like this

```
ID    Name           Parent
1   Manager             0
2   Accountant          0
3   Assistant Manager   1
4   Branch Manager      1
5   Employee1           3
6   Employee3           3
7   Employee2           4
8   Accountant1         2
9   Accountant2         2
```

The parent represents structure of a tree view like this in my asp page

```
*Manager-->Assistant manager-->Employee1
        |                   |->Employee3
        |
        |-->Branch Manager---->Employee2
*Accountant-->Accountant1
           |->Accountant2
```

I only have to use dictionary to show my datatable to treeview
So i did above code to bind datatable to dictionary.
Now trying to bind dictionary to treeview 
Is that clear mates
PS: I'm a newbie in asp

Comment: What kind of values you need to extract? Just `"Name"`s?

Comment: I need "id" and "parent" also. If u tell me how to take first string value and  certain string value from "name" then i will manage. Dictionary has 9 rows btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Find Nested Dictionary Value like this

```
var dt1 = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Test1", 1 }, { "Test2", 1 }, { "Test3", 1 } };
var dt2 = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Test11", 101 }, { "Test22", 201 }, { "Test33", 301 } };

var dt3 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> { { 11, dt1 }, { 22, dt2 } };

foreach (var kvp in dt3)
{
    var innerDict = kvp.Value;

    foreach (var innerKvp in innerDict)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
         Console.WriteLine(innerKvp.Key);
         Console.WriteLine(innerKvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can carry-on with your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Name`s list like below:

```
var namesList = management.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => y.Key));
```

Now just invoke `First()` on the above list to get the first name.

```
string temp = namesList.First();
```